# Where is my subvolume "fedora" located?

Tags: fedora, btrfs, snapshot

When I do :

```
$ btrfs subvolume list /
ID 256 gen 3794 top level 5 path fedora
ID 264 gen 2296 top level 256 path root/snapshots/test
```

I get two subvolumes.

I want to know where the `fedora` subvolume is located.

The `root/snapshots/test` is located in `/root/snapshots/test`, but where is `fedora` ?

When I mount from a live-cd I get:

```
# mount -t btrfs /dev/sda3 /mnt
# ls /mnt
# bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

But no subvolume known as `fedora`. **So where is this subvolume ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `fedora` subvolume is located in your BTRFS top-level volume. Let's take a closer look at your example:

```
$ btrfs subvolume list /
ID 256 gen 3794 top level 5 path fedora
ID 264 gen 2296 top level 256 path root/snapshots/test
```

Now let's format the same information a bit differently (ok, I'm actually adding a bit to it):

```
ID  GEN  PARENT ID  PATH
5   -    -          <ROOT_FS> 
256 3794 5          <ROOT_FS>/fedora
264 2296 256        <ROOT_FS>/fedora/root/snapshots/test
```

What this shows is that `fedora` is a child of subvolume 5, the "top-level" subvolume. In addition, `test` is a child of `fedora`.

Normally, you'd see the top-level subvolume when you mount a BTRFS filesystem. But in your case, the default subvolume was changed to `fedora`, which is why you don't see `fedora` when you mount the filesystem.

You can easily gain access to the top-level subvolume as follows:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt -o subvolid=5
```

Answer (score 2):

`fedora` is the top-level subvolume (you can tell because it has id `5`), it's the default subvolume ("volume" would be probably better terminology) that is always created and you can think about it similarty to `/` in filesystem hierarchy. If you had separate subvolumes for `/` and `/home` (in Fedora called `root` and `home` by default) and mounted the default subvolume (which happens if you mount the btrfs device without `subvolid` option) you'd see `root` and `home` directories and you can't see the `fedora` folder anywhere because it is the top-level subvolume and there is no folder for it internally, `fedora` is only name of the entire btrfs filesystem.

See [btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Subvolumes) or `man btrfs-subvolume` for more information.

Comment: How do I copy all my data to a subvolume ?